# how to assign keys from a fetch request array result and values from a text field input in a empty dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, core-data, swift3

I have a fetch request that returns an array of objects of Floors entity. For each floor entity I assign a value for the "number of rooms per floor" attribute. The next vc is a table where the number of floors need to be the sections and the number of rooms per floor need to be the cells inside that sections. So, the most convenient way that I can think of is to pass a dictionary [floor: roomsInFloor] to prepare for segue. The thing is I cannot get my head around as to how would I set the keys and values for an empty dictionary. I have had a go at it but it is not the correct one and I couldn't find any useful examples on the site. Could someone please explain to me how to do this? Please see code below. Thank you.

```
class SetNumberOfRoomsPerFloor: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

//MARK: - Properties

@IBOutlet private weak var floorPicker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet private weak var numberOfRoomsPerFloor: UITextField!

private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

internal var floorValue: Int16?

private var convertedFloorValues = [String]()

private var storedFloors = [Floors]()

private var pickedFloor: Int16?

private var roomNumberValue: Int16 {
    get {
        return Int16(numberOfRoomsPerFloor.text!)!
    }
}

private var floorsAndRooms = [String: String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    floorPicker.delegate = self
    floorPicker.dataSource = self
    loadFloorData()
    spinnerItems()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func setTheFloors(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if storedFloors.count > 0 {
        if storedFloors.first?.floorNumber == pickedFloor! {
            storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms = roomNumberValue
            print("\(storedFloors.first?.floorNumber) + \(storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms)")
        }
    }
}

private func setTheDictionary() { // this is not correct!
    for i in 0...storedFloors.count - 1 {
        floorsAndRooms.updateValue(String(describing: storedFloors.first?.numberOfRooms), forKey: String(i))
    }
    print("\(floorsAndRooms.count)")
}

@IBAction func nextStep(_ sender: UIButton) {

}

private func loadFloorData() {
    let floorRequest: NSFetchRequest<Floors> = Floors.fetchRequest()
    do {
        storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(floorRequest)
    } catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

private func spinnerItems() {
    for i in 0...floorValue! - 1 {
        convertedFloorValues.append(String(i))
}
// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}



public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return convertedFloorValues.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return convertedFloorValues[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print("\(convertedFloorValues)")
    let selection = Int16(convertedFloorValues[row]) // not sure I have to do this part.
    pickedFloor = selection
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
private func setTheDictionary() {
    for floor in storedFloors {
        floorsAndRooms["\(floor.floorNumber)"] = "\(floor.numberOfRooms)"
    }
}
```

You may want to check out [Apple's Swift Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/).  It's pretty good.  The sections on Control Flow (for iterating) and Collections (for dictionaries) should be quite relevant.  (That's the link for the Swift 3 version.)

Also, note that you didn't give the fetchRequest any sortDescriptors.  So the array you get from CoreData will not be in any particular order, i.e. it won't be in the order of the floor numbers.  It's ok as it is.  You don't need the results sorted since you're storing them in a dictionary, which isn't sorted either.  Just know that when you are inspecting the fetched array, its elements won't be in order.